# Loop Through API: Next Entries field (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, api, loops, pagination

I am trying to extract dart from a REST API that limits returned items to 1000.

The API currently has an `After` field, which means the next 1000 entries. I am trying to store all the loops into a dataframe and I am stuck in this pagination:

```
api_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
entries_per_page = 1000  # API limit
entries = []
payload={}
headers = {'x-api-key': api_token}

def get_entries(limit,start):
  url = "https://api.atendesimples.com/customers/attendants/logs?&size="+str(limit)+"&after="+str(start)
  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
  all_data = response.json()
  data = all_data['items']
  pagination = all_data['after'] # The field that I would like to loop in the URL
  if len(data) > 0:
    for i in range(len(data)):
      entries.append(data[i])
    get_entries(limit,all_data["after"])

get_entries(entries_per_page,"")
df = pd.DataFrame(entries)
```

Whenever I try this, I end up in a infinite loop.

When I run this "all_data", I've got this JSON:

```
Out[4]: {'total': 1295,
 'after': 1636477489502,
 'items': [{'kind_id': '14442.31298.1636551198901.00006',
     'status': 'OPEN'},
    'server_1': {'host': 'instance101'}
```

I would like to store all the 1k entries, then change the `"&after="+str(start)` in the URL to the latest `"after"`.

Comment: Are you sure it's an infinite loop, and not just taking a while because there are a lot of logs?

Comment: Have you confirmed manually that the url `https://api.atendesimples.com/customers/attendants/logs?&size=1000&after=1636477489502` returns expected results?

Comment: Whenever I try the correct after, It works. The problem is that I cannot loop it...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want; it's untested so give it a try. Slightly modified function.

```
def get_entries(limit, start):
    url = "https://api.atendesimples.com/customers/attendants/logs?&size="+str(limit)+"&after="+str(start)
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    all_data = response.json()
    data = all_data['items']
    if len(data) > 0:
      for i in range(len(data)):
        entries.append(data[i])
    after = all_data.get('after')
    return after
```

Run your first iteration outside the while loop. using .get() will fetch the after key:value and if the key isn't there, it'll return None. I'm assuming here the  after key will not be in the json response if there are no more entries. if it is and it's empty or null or something you may have to change the logic.

```
start = 0
after = get_entries(entries_per_page, start)  

# once in the while loop, if after is None, the program with break
while True:
    if after:
        after = get_entries(entries_per_page, after)  
    else:
        break
```